# Name of special blob filling algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, image-processing

I'm using a special case of filling for copped blobs that can not filled by hole filling, the algorithm works as following:

- The rows are scanned, when white pixel is detected then

  - count the number of black pixels until detect a white pixel.
  - replace these black pixels with white pixels.
- repeat this step for all rows.
- This steps are repeated for columns as well.

Example is shown the attached image

[image: example]

What is the name of this algorithm so I can find a reference for it?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'm looking for the name of this algorithm so I can find a reference for it.

Comment: Your description doesn't make much sense. Do you  replace only once per row? Also how come you get to picture 2 from picture 1? Is seems on most rows a white pixel is found right next to the first white pixel

Comment: The pictures do not match the explanation (which by the way is rather ambiguous).

Comment: The question simplified: If black pixels in any row or column are surrounded by white pixels in that same row or column, convert those black pixels to white.

Answer (score 2):

What you are after is an algorithm that leverages the 'convex hull' of a region. The final image above is not convex, but you can generate it by iteratively intersecting the dilation of the region with the convex hull and adding the result to the original image. This adds pixels layer-by-layer to just the concave regions of the original image. This alone will not fill up the central void before the exterior becomes identical to the convex hull, however, and so the trick is to perform hole-filling at every iteration. After 4-5 iterations the 'cave mouth' closes up and the hole filling will take care of the remaining void.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to a succession of two morphological closing operations, respectively with a W x 1 and a 1 x H linear structuring element. A closing is a dilation followed by an erosion with the same structuring element.

Comment: There is no erosion or dilation in the algorithm. Where does it come from? I just want to know the name of this algorithm explained in the question so as to use it as reference in my research.

Comment: I don't think this particular operation has a name. The closest match is a explained.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do this.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('hull.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print("Number of contours detected:", len(contours))
cnt = contours[1]
hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
#img = cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(255,0,0),2)
thickness = -1 #negative thickness fills the contour insides
img = cv2.drawContours(img,[hull],0,(255,255,255),-1) #the colours are (B, G, R)
cv2.imshow("Convex Hull", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: OP’s operation is not a convex hull. It fills in locally concave regions but it doesn’t produce a convex hull. It only adds horizontal or vertical edges.

Comment: Thanks Cris. I realize you are right. Anyway, I hope my answer will help anyone else looking for a convex hull sample, because I reached this page the same way.